# Matching Networks for 915Mhz

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching, pcb-antenna

I'm trying to build a PCB antenna for Lora 915Mhz.

I saw [this Inverted-F Antenna](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN91445_Antenna_Design_and_RF_Layout_Guidelines-ApplicationNotes-v09_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7cdc391c017d073e054f6227) (page 15) and [this one](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra496a/swra496a.pdf?ts=1689096748735) (page 31), but often the matching network used are not indicated.

I was thinking it's just a component I should order then solder (or PCB assembly), and voila. But look like it's more complex. The only thing I know about matching network is that play as a regulator when the antenna have some variations on impedance, and increase efficiency of antenna.
On the last example provided it's look like RK73Z1ETTP was used, which is few resistor 0 Ohm. Can a simple resistor do the trick?
Any easy way to do this?

Comment: You need to match the impedance of your source with the impedance of your line and your antenna. This way, there are no reflections on the line and the antenna can transmitt the maximum power.  This can be a complex task. See Pages 24-42.  Page 40 Figure 44 states "0.7-pF capacitor and a series 1.2-pF capacitor to attain resonance". I Would start with these but also order a "Capacitor Kit" and then get out my VNA to confirm and test =) NOTE: A PCB-Design for RF is more than "routing tracks"!. Makre sure you read about track impedance and stub-lines first!

Comment: Ok, I keep reading, thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Sir, you are welcome!